# Kivy instantly crashing/not responding and app screen goes white

Tags: python, crash, kivy, kivy-language

so I've been learning kivy and was progressing well, I finished for the day and everything worked perfect so I saved and shut off my pc.
The next day I tried to run the code and the kivy window instantly crashed on a white screen (None of the code had been changed and was working fine the day before)...
I get no errors at all. So I made a brand new file containing very basic code that I've even ran on my android so I know the code runs but still get the same issue when trying to run it on my PC.
Has anyone any ideas?... Here's the basic code that runs on my phone but not pc.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class fpage(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(fpage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Name"))
        self.ent1 = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Password"))
        self.ent2 = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.ent1)
        self.add_widget(self.ent2)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return fpage()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Here is the term info:
[image: TERM INFO]

And the app when launched:
[image: APP WHEN RAN]

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out.

---

When first using kivy I had to download a file called "opengl32.dll" to fix a Open Gl error. Which the fix worked.

---

I planned to delete the "opengl32.dll" file and replace it with a fresh one thinking it might have got corrupted but once deleted it worked perfect again

---

Path = %user%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310